# handle JSON file with DOJO

Tags: json, dojo, dojox.charting

As title if I have data in Json as below

```
{ 
  "label": "btmlabel",
  "items": [
        { "mydata":"bla", "btmlabel":"22 April 10.34AM", "data":[{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:3}]}
       ]
}
```

Is that possible for me to modify the data as below...

```
{ 
  "label": "btmlabel",
  "items": [
        { "mydata":"bla", "btmlabel":"22 April 11.00AM", "data":[{x:1,y:1},{x:3,y:4},{x:4,y:5}]}
       ]
}
```

Much appreciate for any help thanks.

Comment: There is no difference between the structures of the two JSON snipplets.  What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is [possible](http://jsfiddle.net/C8a7h/) :)

Answer (score 0):

yes of course.
If I will have more details I can show you how you can change this data.